# Oracle , Infrastructure Regions

Tags: oracle, region

When registering, I got the London region, but I am in Ukraine and I want to select the Frankfurt region. There is a subscription to it, how can I do this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: details of what you were registering; where you were registering it; the details of the code you were using (assuming that this is a programming question - if it is not then it is off topic for StackOverflow); the full details of the issue/error message; and the expected output from your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer service / support issue, not a programming question.